# Open a process from file, in C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, process, system, gnome

I'm coding my application in C++ on Linux. C++ has a function called 'system' to execute a programme.

I try to open the gnome-system-monitor from C++ like this:

```
system("gnome-system-monitor");
```

However, the thread of my application blocks when I call this 'system' function until I close the window of gnome-system-monitor.

Any other ways to open a process from file without blocking the caller process?

Comment: That would be `fork()` followed by one of the `exec()` functions, but this is more low-level and complicated.

Comment: You should create child process with fork/exec, execute gnome-system-monitor in child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic way, which works on any Linux or otherwise POSIX-based system, is

```
if (0 == fork()) {
  execlp("gnome-system-monitor", "gnome-system-monitor", (char *)NULL);
}
```

(with error handling omitted from this example.)  This (a) creates a new process, (b) in that new process, runs "gnome-system-monitor" after searching the PATH environment variable to find such a command, (c) passes it the name "gnome-system-monitor" as argv[0] and no other arguments.  In the parent, once the new process is created it barrels on ahead without waiting for any result.

See the man pages for `fork` and `execlp` for more details.

Comment: how come after calling execlp, my caller thread stops its execution

Comment: A process that calls `execlp` or any of the `exec` family has its program replaced entirely by the new one -- see [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp). That's why you want to `fork` before calling it. Is that what you mean, or something else?

Comment: it seems like fork fails to create process, after that the call to 'exec' replaces my existing process

Comment: Are you checking the return value from `fork`? When it fails, it returns -1 -- see [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork). When it succeeds, it returns in *both* the original (parent) process and the new (child) process; the way you tell the difference is that it returns 0 to the child and returns the child's PID (which is >0) to the parent. You want to `exec` only in the child, i.e. when it returns 0.

Answer (score 1):

fork/exec or posix_spawn. glib also has GSpawn if you are using that.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome is built above GTk (which contains Glib), and you probably want the [Glib Spawning Processes](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) functions.

Of course, on Linux and Unix, [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_process) are [forked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28operating_system%29). Read a good book like
[advanced unix programming](http://basepath.com/aup/) and [advanced linux programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com) to learn more about [syscalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) related to processes, notably [fork(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html), [pipe(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html). Read also about the [proc(5)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html) filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Call System function on a separte thread.